# Canadian personal finance software with ability to export historical credit card transactions?

Tags: canada, credit-card, software, mint.com, transaction

I am looking for a personal finance software that lists all your credit card transactions. I was looking at mint Canada and it has what I want (lists all your credit card transactions and assigns the transaction a category).

However it only goes 30 to 90 days back. I am looking for something in the 6 to 12+ month range.

I need it to support Canadian credit cards and easy for Canadians to sign up(not have to make a fake U.S address)

If they have an api that can be used to get these transactions that would be great otherwise an option allows a user to export the transactions to a csv file would be fine.

Comment: These old transactions: do you have them entered/stored locally, or is the software supposed to download them from the bank?

Comment: For mint it is you hookup you bank/credit card and it gets them from. They do have an option to manually enter it in but that will not work for what I am planning to create(that's why I am looking for something that is automatic)

Comment: The problem might be not with the software but with the bank. The question might be whether the bank (not the software) will keep and let you download transactions, which are more than three months old.

Comment: Yes they can limit but Mint ignore this limit. I heard some banks allow you going back as far as a year. While others only a month, yet mint will only ever do a max of 90 days. So I am looking for something that only limits itself based on the bank limitations not an artificial limitation. I can look at statements in my banks online website and they seem to at least go back a year.

Answer (score 1):

Yodlee is the back-end which communicates with the banks, and Mint just provide a pretty layer on top.

You can sign up for an account with [Yodlee](https://moneycenter.yodlee.com/moneycenter/mfalogin.moneycenter.do?_flowId=mfaloginflow) directly, which may give you the flexibility you need.

Comment: I asked them and it seems like 60 days is a max they will do with transactions. I read that Mint has their own back-end system(they use to use yodlee until they were bought out)

Answer (score 1):

Yodlee and Mint are good solutions if you don't mind your personal financial information being stored "in the cloud". I do, so I use [Quicken](http://quicken.intuit.ca/personal-finance-software/index.jsp).

Quicken stores whatever you give to it for as long as you want: so the only question is how to get the credit card transactions you want into it? All my financial institutions allow me to view my credit card statements for a year back, and download them in a form Quicken can read. So you can have a record of your transactions from a year ago right now, and in a year you will have two year's worth.

Comment: I am looking for more cloud based solutions as I am building a web based solution that will consume the data and I rather have a solution a user does not need to download and pay for. My site really will just consume .csv files in a certain format so they should be able in the end to use anything that gets there transactions but I want to recommend solution.

Comment: Thought you were looking for something for personal use. You might like to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use OFX or QIF files, most Canadian banks can spit output more data than 90 days. The files are typically used to import into Quicken-like local programs, but can be easily parsed for your webapp, I imagine.

Comment: Hmm I will see how that works. I have to see if you can open those formats with a program like notepad and see readable data. Not they use some funky formatting or something

Comment: @chobo2: Include [OFX2CSV](http://www.ofx2csv.com/) in your consideration.